# Azure load balancer data SYNC

Tags: load-balancing, azure-load-balancer

I created Azure load balancer using a scale set. so I have 2 instances of Windows server 2016 running. My web portal is up and running
whenever I try to save data it only gets saved on 1 instance rather than both how can I keep them in SYNC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in data sync feature in Azure Scale Set. However, you could create a scale set by using a custom VM image including all required application installed to reduce the post deployment task.

> When you create a scale set, you specify an image to be used when the
> VM instances are deployed. To reduce the number of tasks after VM
> instances are deployed, you can use a custom VM image. This custom VM
> image includes any required application installs or configurations.
> Any VM instances created in the scale set use the custom VM image and
> are ready to serve your application traffic.

For more references:

[Tutorial: Create and use a custom image for virtual machine scale sets with the Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/tutorial-use-custom-image-cli)

Comment: Thank you, Nancy, that's exactly what I did but I did configure a load balancer. so our end users upload the data to our web portal so data only gets saved on 1 instance so i was trying to find out how can I keep both instances in SYNC. so i came across DFS. do you have any other recommendations?

Comment: It's recommended to use Custom Script Extension or PowerShell DSC. See more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-deploy-app#already-provisioned)

Comment: In the long term, If you use a custom VM image with the application pre-installed, you could integrate the application updates with a deployment pipeline to build the new images and deploy OS upgrades across the scale set. Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-deploy-app#install-applications-with-os-updates).

Comment: Do you have more questions?  If this is helpful, please accept it.